# position: absolute bottom: 0 not working when centering text on image

Tags: html, css, image, absolute

I'm trying to place text in the middle of an image on a page. I'd like to use this on other images on the page with different heights and widths as well. I have the image relatively positioned and the text absolutely positioned, but bottom: 0 doesn't seem to be working:

```
<div class="image">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/">
    <header class="text">
        <h1>header</h1>
        <a href="#">button</a>
    </header>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.image {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.text h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
}

.text a {
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

And a link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yg4Ar/

Comment: `bottom:0` is working perfectly fine in your example – give `.text` a background color, then you’ll see it, the element gets stretched from top to bottom of its container element. (I might not _achieve_ what you want, but that’s a different matter altogether – and a broadly discussed one at that, centering stuff with CSS is a topic almost as old as the web …)

Comment: You have a few misunderstandings about positioning in CSS, one of the being that the position is not to be applied to the children inside the element it is set on but on the element _relative to its parent_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the top to a percentage:

```
.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 0;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: yeah, I figured percentage was the way to go. I'll just have to overwrite the top when I have images of different sizes.

Answer (score 5):

You have :

```
position: absolute;
top: 0; // This keeps text top.
left: 0;
color: white;
text-align: center;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
```

So this makes your text to 100% height.. because of that `top:0`.. so just remove that `top:0`.

And if you want to center your text vertically, you have to specify/calculate some height for your text and add half of it as minus margin to your CSS and put top value to 50% like:

```
.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -30px; // This should be half of your text div:s height
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

`Example:` http://jsfiddle.net/9zyx2/

Comment: Removing 'top:0' "fixes 'bottom: 0'; but, the text is then anchored to the bottom of the image.  The OP's problem really is "trying to place text in the middle of an image".

Comment: Added this option to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.text {
    position:absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: view it here and you will see that it is centered http://jsfiddle.net/yg4Ar/15/
110 may be a better number but as you can see by changing the top value it will move the text down

Comment: Yes, but the image height may vary.. read "I'd like to use this on other images on the page with different heights and widths as well" so what happens when image height is 100px?? I tell you: text div disappears..

Comment: Which is why in my solution, I suggested using a % on the top.